# Does VSCode support Vue without adding extensions?

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code

I seem to have syntax highlighting in VS Code, without installing any specific Vue extensions (in fact, when I run `code --disable-extensions`). However from what I've seen [around the web](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/15438) / friends, a vue extension is needed as VS Code does not support Vue out of the box.

Does it support Vue or not? I checked the release notes of the last few months, haven't found anything Vue related there. And if it does support Vue, why are there a few Vue extensions out there that provide syntax highlighting?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Disclaimer: Former VSCode intern. Working on vetur, a VSCode extension for vue:

- https://github.com/octref/vetur
- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=octref.vetur

**Short answer: No.**

Long answer:

VSCode has been use its html extension for vue SFC. That works fine with html/css/js, but not pug/sass/scss/less/stylus/typescript/coffee.

By "works fine", I mean VSCode has correct syntax highlighting, some IntelliSense, formatter and error checking, for html/css/js.

VSCode has no intention to add vue-specific support in its html extension, like scss support, etc. So I started to work on vetur. Initially I just wanted better syntax highlighting, but now I have reworked vue component's grammar and ported VSCode's html extension to support vue, so you get complete syntax highlighting, some IntelliSense, error-checking and formatting.

Here is a list of implemented features:

- Basic IntelliSense for html/css/scss/less/js
- Linting for css/scss/less/js
- Syntax highlighting for:

  - html/jade/pug
  - css/sass/scss/less/stylus
  - js/ts
- Embedded snippet support

  - Use vue snippet outside all regions
  - Use each language's snippet inside its region
- emmet for html/css/sass/scss/less

[image]

Comment: Hi, many thanks for making vetur. I'm not being able to make this work for some reason. Apparently, no one else is having this problem; so I must be missing something obvious. This is what I did: 1. installed vetur, 2. downloaded veturpack, 3. ran yarn and yarn dev from inside veturpack folder. 4. opened folder in vs code. Nothing works. I also tried adding a jsconfig.json file with `include": [ "./client/**/*" ]`. Did the same in tsconfig as well. Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks again.

Comment: Forgot to add: VS Code 0.13.1, vetur 0.9.0, Node 8.1.3, Windows 10. vetur is the only extension installed.

Comment: Never mind. The problem was very simple. I had earlier configured my .vue files to be read as html. Just had to change the language to vue.

Answer (score 0):

Vue is just a javascript library so, yes, you can edit Vue code in VSCode.  However, there's things like "[Single File Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html)" that make using Vue much, much easier.  VSCode can edit .vue files as well, but to process those you need something like webpack or Browserify to post-process them into browser-friendly code.